# How to import crypto js in react native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to import 'crypto-js' using react native.following is the code

> import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

after using this code I got following error:

error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `crypto-js` from file `/Users/hjw143/Documents/PropertyFinder/SearchPage.js`, the package `/Users/hjw143/Documents/PropertyFinder/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/hjw143/Documents/PropertyFinder/node_modules/crypto-js/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `crypto-js` in my project but I import the lib this way:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
```

Try that and tell me if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question.Actually that import statement was correct. I got error because that 'crypto-js' libraries and it's files permission are read only.

By setting that file permission to read-write,error went away.